# Rotate through chromium tabs on raspberry pi?

Tags: bash, google-chrome, scripting, raspberry-pi, chromium

We have several TVs, each with a Raspberry Pi hooked up, so they can be used as information dashboards. The current setup stays on one tab the entire time.

I am trying to set it up so that it will automatically rotate through the chromium tabs every 15 seconds, but am not sure how to approach this.

The Pi's, as far as I know, only have a headless OS with chromium installed, which is started on boot in the xinitrc file.

I know there are some chrome plugins that can do this, but I don't think they can be installed on the command line.

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You can use xdotool with watch to do this:

```
# rotate tabs after 30 seconds.
watch -n30 "xdotool search --onlyvisible --class chromium key ctrl+Tab"
```